# How to download a video while playing it, using ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

### Background

I'm working on an app that can play some short videos.

I want to avoid accessing the Internet every time the user plays them, to make it faster and to lower the data usage.

### The problem

Currently I've only found how to either play or download (it's just a file so I could download it like any other file).

Here's the code of playing a video file from URL (sample available **here**):

**gradle**

```
...
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.8.4'
...
```

**manifest**

```
<manifest package="com.example.user.myapplication" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:resize_mode="zoom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        playVideo()
    }

    private fun playVideo() {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this@MainActivity, DefaultTrackSelector())
        playerView.player = player
        player!!.addVideoListener(object : VideoListener {
            override fun onVideoSizeChanged(width: Int, height: Int, unappliedRotationDegrees: Int, pixelWidthHeightRatio: Float) {
            }

            override fun onRenderedFirstFrame() {
                Log.d("appLog", "onRenderedFirstFrame")
            }
        })
        player!!.addListener(object : PlayerEventListener() {
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                super.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState)
                when (playbackState) {
                    Player.STATE_READY -> Log.d("appLog", "STATE_READY")
                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> Log.d("appLog", "STATE_BUFFERING")
                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> Log.d("appLog", "STATE_IDLE")
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> Log.d("appLog", "STATE_ENDED")
                }
            }
        })
        player!!.volume = 0f
        player!!.playWhenReady = true
        player!!.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
        player!!.playVideoFromUrl(this@MainActivity, "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mkv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mkv")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        playerView.player = null
        player!!.release()
        player = null
    }


    abstract class PlayerEventListener : Player.EventListener {
        override fun onPlaybackParametersChanged(playbackParameters: PlaybackParameters?) {}
        override fun onSeekProcessed() {}
        override fun onTracksChanged(trackGroups: TrackGroupArray?, trackSelections: TrackSelectionArray?) {}
        override fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException?) {}
        override fun onLoadingChanged(isLoading: Boolean) {}
        override fun onPositionDiscontinuity(reason: Int) {}
        override fun onRepeatModeChanged(repeatMode: Int) {}
        override fun onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(shuffleModeEnabled: Boolean) {}
        override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline?, manifest: Any?, reason: Int) {}
        override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {}
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun getUserAgent(context: Context): String {
            val packageManager = context.packageManager
            val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0)
            val appName = info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
            return Util.getUserAgent(context, appName)
        }
    }

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri) {
        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, MainActivity.getUserAgent(context))
        val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri)
        prepare(mediaSource)
    }


    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFromUrl(context: Context, url: String) = playVideoFromUri(context, Uri.parse(url))

    fun SimpleExoPlayer.playVideoFile(context: Context, file: File) = playVideoFromUri(context, Uri.fromFile(file))
}
```

### What I've tried

I've tried reading on the docs, and got those links (by asking about it [**here**](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4650) ) :

https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/downloading-streams-6d259eec7f95
https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/downloading-adaptive-streams-37191f9776e

So sadly, currently the only solution I can come up with, is to download the file on another thread, which will cause the device to have 2 connections to it, thus using twice the bandwidth.

### The questions

1. How can I use ExoPlayer to play a video file, while also downloading it to some filepath ?
2. Is there a way to enable a caching mechanism (which uses the disk) on ExoPlayer to be activated for the exact same purpose?

Note: To make it clear. I do not want to download the file and only then play it.

---

EDIT: I've found a way to get&use the file from the API's cache (wrote about it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53704530/878126)), but it appears that this is considered as unsafe (written [**here**](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5569#issuecomment-470081053)).

So, given the simple cache mechanism that the API of ExoPlayer supports, my current questions are:

1. If a file was cached, how can I use it in a safe manner?
2. If a file was partially cached (meaning we've downloaded a part of it), how can I continue preparing it (without actually playing it or waiting for the whole playback to finish) till I can use it (in a safe manner of course) ?

I've made a Github repository for this [**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ExoPlayerCacheSample). You can try it out.

Comment: I am not a Expert on `Exo`. But some times ago i was just messing around with it and i came across [This](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache). The whole idea is using a Proxy. You can have a look at the implementation .

Comment: @ADM Looks promising, but I asked how to do it in the official way, or as closer to have a cache that's possible, using the official way. I will give you +1 because it might just be what we will use (i need to think about it, and see if indeed it fits our case), and since you took the effort to help, so thank you, but I hope to see a real solution here.

Comment: yeah,not long ago,i think the problem too.maybe it need to build a connection between your client and your server. i find a project in the github website.it may be solve your problem. like below:
[AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I took a look at erdemguven's sample code [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5569) and seem to have something that works. This is by-and-large what erdemguven wrote, but I write to a file instead of a byte array and create the data source. I am thinking that since erdemguven, who is an ExoPlayer expert, presented this as the correct way to access cache, that my mods are also "correct" and do not break any rules.

Here is the code. `getCachedData` is the new stuff.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CacheDataSource.EventListener, TransferListener {

    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

    companion object {
        // About 10 seconds and 1 meg.
//        const val VIDEO_URL = "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"

        // About 1 minute and 5.3 megs
        const val VIDEO_URL = "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"

        // The full movie about 355 megs.
//        const val VIDEO_URL = "http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4"

        // Use to download video other than the one you are viewing. See #3 test of the answer.
//        const val VIDEO_URL_LIE = "http://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"

        // No changes in code deleted here.

    //NOTE: I know I shouldn't use an AsyncTask. It's just a sample...
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    fun tryShareCacheFile() {
        // file is cached and ready to be used
        object : AsyncTask<Void?, Void?, File>() {
            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): File {
                val tempFile = FilesPaths.FILE_TO_SHARE.getFile(this@MainActivity, true)
                getCachedData(this@MainActivity, cache, VIDEO_URL, tempFile)
                return tempFile
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: File) {
                super.onPostExecute(result)
                val intent = prepareIntentForSharingFile(this@MainActivity, result)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }.execute()
    }

    private var mTotalBytesToRead = 0L
    private var mBytesReadFromCache: Long = 0
    private var mBytesReadFromNetwork: Long = 0

    @WorkerThread
    fun getCachedData(
        context: Context, myCache: Cache?, url: String, tempfile: File
    ): Boolean {
        var isSuccessful = false
        val myUpstreamDataSource = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(ExoPlayerEx.getUserAgent(context)).createDataSource()
        val dataSource = CacheDataSource(
            myCache,
            // If the cache doesn't have the whole content, the missing data will be read from upstream
            myUpstreamDataSource,
            FileDataSource(),
            // Set this to null if you don't want the downloaded data from upstream to be written to cache
            CacheDataSink(myCache, CacheDataSink.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE.toLong()),
            /* flags= */ 0,
            /* eventListener= */ this
        )

        // Listen to the progress of the reads from cache and the network.
        dataSource.addTransferListener(this)

        var outFile: FileOutputStream? = null
        var bytesRead = 0

        // Total bytes read is the sum of these two variables.
        mTotalBytesToRead = C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()
        mBytesReadFromCache = 0
        mBytesReadFromNetwork = 0

        try {
            outFile = FileOutputStream(tempfile)
            mTotalBytesToRead = dataSource.open(DataSpec(Uri.parse(url)))
            // Just read from the data source and write to the file.
            val data = ByteArray(1024)

            Log.d("getCachedData", "<<<<Starting fetch...")
            while (bytesRead != C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT) {
                bytesRead = dataSource.read(data, 0, data.size)
                if (bytesRead != C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT) {
                    outFile.write(data, 0, bytesRead)
                }
            }
            isSuccessful = true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // error processing
        } finally {
            dataSource.close()
            outFile?.flush()
            outFile?.close()
        }

        return isSuccessful
    }

    override fun onCachedBytesRead(cacheSizeBytes: Long, cachedBytesRead: Long) {
        Log.d("onCachedBytesRead", "<<<<Cache read? Yes, (byte read) $cachedBytesRead (cache size) $cacheSizeBytes")
    }

    override fun onCacheIgnored(reason: Int) {
        Log.d("onCacheIgnored", "<<<<Cache ignored. Reason = $reason")
    }

    override fun onTransferInitializing(source: DataSource?, dataSpec: DataSpec?, isNetwork: Boolean) {
        Log.d("TransferListener", "<<<<Initializing isNetwork=$isNetwork")
    }

    override fun onTransferStart(source: DataSource?, dataSpec: DataSpec?, isNetwork: Boolean) {
        Log.d("TransferListener", "<<<<Transfer is starting isNetwork=$isNetwork")
    }

    override fun onTransferEnd(source: DataSource?, dataSpec: DataSpec?, isNetwork: Boolean) {
        reportProgress(0, isNetwork)
        Log.d("TransferListener", "<<<<Transfer has ended isNetwork=$isNetwork")
    }

    override fun onBytesTransferred(
        source: DataSource?,
        dataSpec: DataSpec?,
        isNetwork: Boolean,
        bytesTransferred: Int
    ) {
        // Report progress here.
        if (isNetwork) {
            mBytesReadFromNetwork += bytesTransferred
        } else {
            mBytesReadFromCache += bytesTransferred
        }

        reportProgress(bytesTransferred, isNetwork)
    }

    private fun reportProgress(bytesTransferred: Int, isNetwork: Boolean) {
        val percentComplete =
            100 * (mBytesReadFromNetwork + mBytesReadFromCache).toFloat() / mTotalBytesToRead
        val completed = "%.1f".format(percentComplete)
        Log.d(
            "TransferListener", "<<<<Bytes transferred: $bytesTransferred isNetwork=$isNetwork" +
                    " $completed% completed"
        )
    }

    // No changes below here.
}
```

Here is what I did to test this and this is by no means exhaustive:

1. Simply shared through email the video using the FAB. I received the video and was able to play it.
2. Turned off all network access on a physical device (airplane mode = on) and shared the video via email. When I turned the network back on (airplane mode = off), I received and was able to play the video. This shows that the video had to come from cache since the network was not available.
3. Changed the code so that instead of `VIDEO_URL` being copied from cache, I specified that `VIDEO_URL_LIE` should be copied. (The app still played only `VIDEO_URL`.) Since I had not downloaded the video for `VIDEO_URL_LIE`, the video was not in cache, so the app had to go out to the network for the video. I successfully received the correct video though email and was able to play it. This shows that the app can access the underlying asset if cache is not available.

I am by no means an ExoPlayer expert, so you will be able to stump me quickly with any questions that you may have.

---

The following code will track progress as the video is read and stored in a local file.

```
// Get total bytes if known. This is C.LENGTH_UNSET if the video length is unknown.
totalBytesToRead = dataSource.open(DataSpec(Uri.parse(url)))

// Just read from the data source and write to the file.
val data = ByteArray(1024)
var bytesRead = 0
var totalBytesRead = 0L
while (bytesRead != C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT) {
    bytesRead = dataSource.read(data, 0, data.size)
    if (bytesRead != C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT) {
        outFile.write(data, 0, bytesRead)
        if (totalBytesToRead == C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
            // Length of video in not known. Do something different here.
        } else {
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead
            Log.d("Progress:", "<<<< Percent read: %.2f".format(totalBytesRead.toFloat() / totalBytesToRead))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will check later what you did, but you aren't supposed to use the code of `cacheSpan` and `cachedFile` , as it was my "bad" solution...

Comment: @androiddeveloper That was dead code. I deleted it. In the meantim, it seems that a separate cache was being created when `myCache` was identified as a `SimpleCache` instead of just a `Cache` in `getCachedData()`. This resulted in a significant delay on the first share of the video due to a re-fetch of data (? not sure). Anyway, there is no longer a delay in the sharing of data if in the cache.

Comment: Also, is it possible to avoid copying and just renaming the file, in case it's already cached? Or is this dangerous too?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I think that is the dangerous part. According to ojw28 [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2711) "It's not correct to assume that we cache the media as a simple file." `CacheDataSource` hides the details of the underlying implementation and make access to the cache _look_ like a simple file so it's "safe." That is my understanding.

Comment: I see. I don't understand the purpose of `VIDEO_URL_LIE`. I don't see it being used anywhere... Is it to test a large video?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I mention `VIDEO_URL_LIE` in test #3 of the answer. It's a link to a video that has not been downloaded to make sure that the logic can download and use a file that is not in the cache. Just change the URL passed to `getCachedData()` to `VIDEO_URL_LIE` and the spinning world video should be download and shared instead of the playing video.

Comment: So it's possible to actually playing while downloading, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Your demo app definitely plays while downloading. Use this video  http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4 to see how it's working. The video is 10.5 minutes long and the file is over 355 megs, so sharing might be a problem.

Comment: I think you wrote `cache` instead of `myCache` in your function. I've tried the code you wrote. Seems to work well. I suggest for it to be annotated with `@WorkerThread` and return true/false depending on whether it succeeded or not. I'd like to ask though: how can I know how much bytes it wrote compared to how much it's supposed to (meaning percentage), when possible? During debug, I can see that `dataSource` has `bytesRemaining` , but it's hidden for some reason, and I don't see an alternative. Maybe `dataSource.open` returns the total bytes it needs to download/read?

Comment: Anyway, I've granted you the bounty. Will give +1 if you succeed to detect the progress as it downloads.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Added transfer listener

Comment: Shouldn't `reportProgress` be called on the `while` loop you have, to support both the partial cached data and the network?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Network traffic and cache traffic are both reported as it is currently written. Progress could also be reported in the while loop if writes to the file is what is being tracked which may be more appropriate. I am tracking progress as it downloads or is read from cache.

Comment: So it's the same ? I think it's nicer to avoid being dependent on the listener and also actually pass along from one listener to another. You would probably have written less too, as you wouldn't have to write the extra functions of the interface... I think it could be cool if you added this solution too, but a promise is a promise. You get +1.

Comment: @androiddeveloper True. But I just wanted to show all the touch points for the TransferListener and it seems that only there can the distinction be made between what is downloaded and what is from cache.

Comment: Could you please show below the answer, what exactly should I put in the loop, to offer this without the extra listener (just the needed change, no need for entire code...).

Comment: @androiddeveloper You want a report in the read/write while loop of how many bytes have been written to the temp file vs how many are in the video total? Enough data to run a progress bar without resorting to the `TransferListener`? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but no need for full code. Just the part of what to put in the `while` loop...

Comment: Thank you for your help. Here, get another +1 . :)

Comment: How I add pause/resume functionaility to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can use exoplayer's SimpleCache with LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor to cache while streaming. Code would look something like.

```
temporaryCache = new SimpleCache(new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "player"), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(bytesToCache));
cacheSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(temporaryCache, buildDataSourceFactory(), CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR);
```

Comment: This is the initialization of 2 variables. How does it get integrated with the player classes? Where does it get "glued" to the code I wrote? Can you please show a more "full" code for it? Where in my code should I add it? Where is the implementation of "buildDataSourceFactory" ? EDIT: found the way to do it. Will post an answer soon

Comment: @deepakkumar Why do you ask me about it, when I'm the one who asked about it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper As you have mentioned above that: `found the way to do it. Will post an answer soon`

Comment: @deepakkumar And I have, and deleted it because someone else has posted a better answer, which I've accepted.