Can I share the cached videos from the cache by DownloadingManager ExoPlayer3?
I am caching the videos by DownloadingManager from ExoPlayer3. Now I want to share it with other applications as .mp4 files. Is it possible with ExoPlayer cache or I need to download that video in the gallery first to do so?
Update: I am using the SimpleCache for caching. I do have access to the cache directory as it is my app's internal storage. But the problem is when I inspect my app's internal directory for caching, I can see a bunch of folders there and files inside them, ending with .exo extension. I am using video uri as a cache key. Now if I have a video uri how can I access its cached files in my cache directory? Files have different names than cache keys.

Please tell full path of cache.

An Android device has no gallery. Unclear what you mean.

If your app has access to the cache you can share it from there.

I think this answer would be relevant to your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55260753
